# Change of temperature upon dilution

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature, entropy

Consider a concentrated dye solution, say 10µM of Rhodamine 6G in water, which is rapidly diluted down to 10nM in an open container. I'm trying to estimate the (presumably minute) temperature change, assuming both solutions (dye and water) are initially at the same room temperature. I believe dilution increases entropy ever so slightly, but I'm struggling to turn this statement into a quantitative temperature change. Specifically, how do I calculate the change in entropy? Once I know this, the change in temperature [should be straight-forward](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/37861/17170).

Comment: You need to measure the heat of mixing of the solute and solvent.

Comment: @ChesterMiller sure, I could (try to) measure the temperature change, but I'm trying to estimate it theoretically.

Comment: Why are you concerned with entropy but not with enthalpy contribution?

Comment: Also 10µM is particularly concentrated. You could get like 10 mM or more depending on counterion.

Comment: @Alchimista if enthalpy is more relevant please provide an explanation. I'm after the temperature change, and I assumed it would occur because of a change in entropy but maybe there's another contribution, I'm quite rusty on all this.

Comment: @Mithoron yes, I provided those numbers for completeness but hopefully with a formula it'd be easy to estimate various cases, including higher concentrations. I picked 10µM because typically beyond that there's a lot of dimers which we tend to avoid for other reasons (spectral changes), but that's irrelevant here.

Comment: I have no idea honestly.  Just T changes can have both nature.  I cannot imagine any experiment in which I would worry for such a T change " if any" . But it doesn't mean that the question shouldn't be asked. I an afraid, however, that without tabulated values then one has to measure that....

Answer (score 2):

At such low concentrations, can’t you just assume an ideal solution? Then the  change in entropy from mixing would be $\Delta S = -R(x_A\ln x_A + x_B \ln x_B)$. But because the solution is so dilute, you can see that both terms are going to be essentially zero. (For a 10 nM solution, the contribution from entropy of mixing is on the order of $10^{-8}$ J K$^{-1}$ mol$^{-1}$.)

The dilution process would thus *lower* the total entropy, since there’s less uncertainty in the system. (You’d get the value you compute at 10 nM, the final state, minus the value at 10 µM, the initial state.)

Comment: sorry what's $x_A$? I do expect the answer to be small, but is it $10^{-10}K$ small or more like $10^{-2}K$

Comment: I'd expect something in between, like $10^{-5}$ or $10^{-6}$.

Comment: The x’s are mole fractions of solute and solvent.

Comment: I’ve included an order estimate in my answer.

Comment: A solution typically does not approach ideal solution behavior at low concentrations (particularly for an aqueous ionic solution).  This would only be the case if you were mixing molecules that have very similar molecular characteristics.  The activity coefficient at infinite dilution in a liquid solution usually deviates maximally from unity.

Comment: @ChesterMiller Fine. But my basic argument—that the effects is essentially negligible—is valid unless the activity coefficients are enormous. And there’s enough difficulty in the computation of activity coefficients that unless you have the specifics for the material you’re using, you can’t guess or assume them in advance.

Comment: The question is about the heat of dilution, and the tiny effect (presumably approaching linear deviation with concentration) of further dilution.   This is governed by the behavior of the activity coefficient variation of the solute as its concentration approaches zero (where the activity coefficient it typically varying very rapidly).  I agree that this would usually be determined only with the use of experimental data.

Comment: Thanks, I can see how this works. Experimental data is likely hard to obtain in this regime